# Acer Aspire E15 dual boot problem

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uefi, acer

Original question: [Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot/630662)

I followed the instructions in the top voted answer and it worked perfectly. Recently it stopped working. When I choose grubx64 in the uefi boot menu it just skips straight to Windows. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot ubuntu with usb
Then go to ubuntu live
Open command prompt
Try this direct command

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg